# How to add new entry in RxMap

Tags: flutter, get, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, state-management

By using getX, i was trying to modify changes to RxMap. But I couldnot find the way to add value to map. add() is not defined at all for RxMap.
putIfAbsent() is not adding up new entry to RxMap.

```
class RestaurantController extends GetxController {
RxMap<String, String> reviews = <String, String>{}.obs;
addReview(String name, String review) {
    reviews.putIfAbsent(name, () => review);
  }
}
```

I tried calling addReview with the help of TextButton as

```
 TextButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all<double>(10.0),
                    backgroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.orange)),
                child: const Text("Submit"),
                onPressed: () {
                  restaurantController.addReview(
                      nameController.text, reviewController.text);
                      
                  print("submitted");
                }),
```

On click, the print statement gets executed, still map is not updated. How can I add new key, value pairs to reviews? I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have the following map in our controller:

```
RxMap<String, String> map = RxMap();
```

To add data to this map we can do:

```
_controller.map.addAll({'hello': 'bye'});
```

Now, if we print map, the following will be printed as it is added to map:

```
{hello: bye}
```

Now, if we do with putIfAbset:

```
_controller.map.putIfAbsent('hello', () => 'bello');
```

The console print will still be the same as the key is already present in map so nothing will be added.
But if we change the above code to this:

```
_controller.map.putIfAbsent('lol', () => 'bello');
```

Now, if we print to console we will see:

```
{hello: bye, lol: bello}
```

To add value to an empty map it's better to use addAll. Use putIfAbsent if you are sure you have same key.

Your code looks right to me as you can also add values to map your way. Just try to print to console everytime you click submit button. Probably it is saving data to your map, without Obx or rebuilds you really cannot see changes in your widget.

Comment: It's not helping. Using addAll() is not adding the entry to RxMap. I have used Obx as well.

Comment: Solved, i missed to include controller in one of the extracted widget. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

You create your RxMap was like

**RxMap<String, String> reviews = <String, String>{}.obs;**

Case 1 : Change inside GetXController

```
Add new Element 
reviews['yourNewkey'] = 'newValue'; // Map <String,String>

Update existing Element
reviews.update("yourKey", (_) => "yourUpdateValue"); 
// Here with help of key (existing key) you update your value
```

Case 2 : Change outside from GetXController

Consider you make GetXController and name is controller

```
Add New Element 
controller.reviews['yourNewkey'] ="newValue";

Update existing Element 
controller.reviews.update("yourKey", (value) => "yourUpdateValue");
```